# Nested form in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have an `Inquiry` which has many `InquiryItem` model which has many `InquiryItemPrice`.

In my show view, I'm looping through my `inquiry_items` and for each of those, I need and input field for `inquiry_item_price`.

Those are my models:

**Inquiry**

```
class Inquiry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :inquiry_items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :inquiry_items, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: lambda { |a| a[:item_id].blank? && a[:quantity].blank? }
end
```

**InquiryItem**

```
class InquiryItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inquiry
  belongs_to :item
  has_many :inquiry_item_prices

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :inquiry_item_prices, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: lambda { |a| a[:item_id].blank? && a[:quantity].blank? }
end
```

**InquiryItemPrices**

```
class InquiryItemPrices < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inquiry_items
end
```

**InquiriesController**

```
  def show
    @request = Inquiry.find(params[:id])
    @request.inquiry_items.each { |item| item.inquiry_item_prices.build}
  end
```

**show.html.slim**

```
    -@inquiry.inquiry_items.each do |inquiry_item|
      tr
        td =inquiry_item.item.name
        td =inquiry_item.quantity
        =f.fields_for :inquiry_item_prices do |builder|
          td =builder.text_field :price, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Preço"
```

With this code I'm load an input for `price`, like this:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Preço" type="text" name="inquiry[inquiry_item_prices][price]" id="inquiry_inquiry_item_prices_price">
```

And the problem is that it is not a list so I'll get only the last field value, it should be like this:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Preço" type="text" name="inquiry[inquiry_item_prices][0][price]" id="inquiry_inquiry_item_prices_0_price">
```

How can I load `InquiryItemPrice` properly and generate those input fields?

Comment: You said `inquiry_items` has_many `inquiry_item_prices` but in the code there is `inquiry_item_distributor_prices` written in several places. Please confirm on this.

Comment: @Pavan Hey, sorry for that, it was a test I was doing, I have edited the question, the correct is `inquiry_item_prices`.

Comment: Try changing this line `=f.fields_for :inquiry_item_prices do |builder|` to `=inquiry_item.fields_for :inquiry_item_prices do |builder|`

Comment: @Pavan `undefined method 'fields_for' for #<InquiryItem:0x007fd6a1d89328>`

Comment: Change the association in your `InquiryItemPrice` model to `belongs_to :inquiry_item`

Comment: @Pavan, any new ideas? Can you help me in the chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is just an update on my `show.html.slim` `form` tag file

```
=form_for(@inquiry, url: inquiry_add_prices_path(@inquiry)) do |f|
      table class="table table-striped"
        thead
          tr
            th Nome
            th Quantidade
            th Valor
        tbody
          =f.fields_for :inquiry_items do |item_form|
            tr
              td =item_form.object.item.name
              td =item_form.object.quantity
              =item_form.fields_for :inquiry_item_prices do |price_form|
                td =price_form.text_field :price, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Preço"

          =f.submit "Enviar preços", class: "btn btn-success"
```

With that it is not required to loop through the @inquiry.inquiry_items since they are being built in the controller `show` method.